# Javascript code to sort elements on an HTML table according to their inner Text (using Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, sorting, html-table

i am trying to create an absence table which will contain names of people that did not came for work for specific month / year .

I am importing all the data from an excel sheet into MariaDB and i display then in an HTML table with a group concat Query that you will see in my model.

**controller function that draws data**

```
public function fobmonth($year,$month){
    
    $data['filtered']=$this->hrma_model->filtered($fbmonth, $fyear);
    $data['allattdata']=$this->hrma_model->get_attdata($year,$month);
    /*load preview view form*/

    $this->load->view('attend',$data);
}
```

**Model function to send the data to controller**

```
public function filtered($fbmonth,$fyear){
   $query=$this->db->query("SELECT fobname,GROUP_CONCAT(fobattend ORDER BY fobday SEPARATOR '<td 
   style=display:none;>') AS fobattendstack, GROUP_CONCAT(fobday ORDER BY fobday SEPARATOR '<td>') as 
fobdaystack FROM tblattend2 WHERE fobmonth=$fbmonth AND fobyear=$fyear GROUP by fobname");
    return $query->result();
}
```

**View**

```
<table class="table table-striped custom-table mb-0" id="my_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Employee</th>
<th>01</th>
<th>02</th>
<th>03</th>
<th>04</th>
<th>05</th>
<th>06</th>
<th>07</th>
<th>08</th>
<th>09</th>
<th>10</th>
<th>11</th>
<th>12</th>
<th>13</th>
<th>14</th>
<th>15</th>
<th>16</th>
<th>17</th>
<th>18</th>
<th>19</th>
<th>20</th>
<th>21</th>
<th>22</th>
<th>23</th>
<th>24</th>
<th>25</th>
<th>26</th>
<th>27</th>
<th>28</th>
<th>29</th>
<th>30</th>
<th>31</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tablebd">
<tr>
<?php foreach($filtered as $filter) {?>
<td><i style="color: #84c529;"><?php echo $filter->fobname;?></i></td>
<td><?php echo $filter->fobdaystack; ?></td> 
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Table looks like that:
[table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDtdE.png)

**Problem**
As you can see the days of attendance are seperated from the Query with a td , what i want is to make a javascript code to run in every tr and td and sort the numbers in the correct order. For example 3 should be under 3 and 5 under 5.
The table elements look like this:
[table elelemnts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfpBx.png)

Now that you understand my issue i have created this javascript :

```
        let trElement=document.getElementsByTagName('tr')
for(let i=1; i<31; i++){
    for(let j=1;j<31; j++){ 
    let sort=trElement[i].children[j]
    if(sort.innerHTML=="1"){
        sort.innerHTML='Y'
    }else if(sort.innerHTML=="2"){
        sort.innerHTML='Y'
    }else if(sort.innerHTML=="3"){
        sort.innerHTML='Y'
    }else if(sort.innerHTML=='4'){
        sort.innerHTML='Y'
    }else if(sort.innerHTML=='5'){
        sort.innerHTML='Y'
    }else if(sort.innerHTML=='6'){
        sort.innerHTML='Y'
    }else if(sort.innerHTML=='7'){
        sort.innerHTML='Y'
    }else if(sort.innerHTML=='8'){
        sort.innerHTML='Y'
    }else if(sort.innerHTML=="9"){
        sort.innerHTML='Y'
    }

    }
    
    }
```

It is just an example to check if i can sort at least the days up to 9. The script works only for the first  tr and then it stops and doesnt work for the rest. Any idea?

Comment: Why are you trying to use sorting to fix a bad display? Fix the displaying code to immediately deliver what you need.

Comment: You also seem to be creating invalid markup. You open `<tr>` before the loop, but close it multiple times inside the loop.

Comment: Fetching data from the query as HTML is also a very bad practice. Separate the actual data from the way it's going to be displayed. Fetch only the values you need and then use PHP to create the view how you want it.

Comment: Two issues that you cant fix with Display . 1st one : The query returns multiple days for each name, concatenated together BUT not in a form of an Array, i have tried explode and no it doesnt work either, so the only option i had to do was to seperate it with a td.
2nd issue: i grab the tr element outside of for loop correctly and when it enters for loop the trelement[i]  remains the same( e.g 1 for first loop) but the children[j] changes till it reaches 31. this way i iterate through each tr each TD . If i try it on console log, it works but as a whole script it doesnt.

Comment: I know query with HTML is bad example but if i seprate with , or "" it will be displayed as an array with one string inside. For example it will return 1,2,3,4,5,6,8 and all of this will have length 1 and it will be one string. i  dont know why it does that else i could have fixied the issue from before

Comment: That's still the wrong approach. Just because you hadn't succeeded getting the data from the database in a fitting format doesn't mean it can't be done and that you should try and fix it at the other end. I'd suggest posting a question about retreiving that data as an array instead of a concatenated string and removing this one. You'll thank yourself in the future.

Comment: Answer to _"i grab the tr element outside of for loop correctly"_ - that's not what I was talking about. I was talking about the `foreach` where you *generate* the table.